# PHP appending/ joining variables

Tags: php, variables

I have the following code:

```
if ($results["q".$i]==$p)...
```

This works fine, however, I am trying to append/ join further variables at the end and am struggling, I need to add `$w[$m]`, I have tried the following but no joy.

```
if ($results["q".$i$w[$m]]==$p)...
```

Also but again, no joy

```
if ($results["q".$i."".$w[$m]]==$p)
```

Any ideas or auggestions?

Comment: `if ($results["q".$i.$w[$m]] === $p)` - strict comparison all the things.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Use a multidimentional array. `$results["q"][$i]` etc..

Comment: Well...I gathered I was doing it wrong! ;-)  Thanks Jimbo - appreciated.

Comment: Post a print_r of the $results array. `print_r($results)`. Then we can see the structure of the actual array and show you how to get what you want.

Comment: Jimbo - works a treat - thanks.

Comment: Interested to understand the downvotes - anyway care to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is the concatenation character. So:

```
if ($results["q".$i.$w[$m]]==$p)...
```

Concatenate `q` with `$i` followed by `$w[$m]`.

Comment: The last form reported to be tried, while having an extra `.""`, has the same semantics. Yet the poster reported the attempted resulted in "no joy" so ..

Comment: Appreciated - thank you - I implemented a long winded way, overcomplicating something which is very straightforward.

Comment: @user2864740 - thanks, you are quite right and I am trying to determine why my approach didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Concatenation is done with the `.` operator. It's done between strings (or expressions that can be evaluated as strings).

So for your specific problem:

```
$result["q" . $i . $w[$m]]
```

## However!

You are doing it **wrong!**

*General Rule:* If you need concatenation inside of array keys, you need a multidimensional array.

So in your case, I'd structure the array differently, so that I may have

```
$result["q"][$i][$w[$m]]
```

Also note, this is *still* not the best it can get. But without knowing how `$w` is structured, I cannot help you further.

## Also

- Strict comparison will usually save you a lot of headache:

  ```
  if ($result["q" . $i . $w[$m]] === $p)
  ```
- It might be possible that your variables are not what you think they are. Use `var_dump()` to discover what's the actual value of `$result["q" . $i . $w[$m]]` and `$p`.

Comment: Madara - thanks - appreciate the feedback.  As I said - I am well, well aware I am doing it wrong - otherwise I wouldn't have posted on 'stackoverflow' asking for advice and assistance.

Comment: @Madara Uchiha You obviously have not noticed [*anything peculiar*](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1640606/qe-uomis) hmm ?

Comment: @Qǝuoɯᴉs: Hmm? I don't follow?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha  [This user has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 81 days](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1640606/qe-uomis).